# CVS utf-8 issue

Tags: cvs

I am using CVS for code repository.
I have a file in CVS which has some characters which cant be represented in ASCII.
Hence to run the code I have to first save the file as UTF-8 and then compile the code.
I want that when I check out the file it should get checked out as UTF-8.
How can I achieve this? Pls help.

Comment: What happens when you try? You may need to mark the file `-kb` binary.

Comment: Show me your `cvs version` output

Answer (score 1):

That is refering the file name or the content inside the source?
AFAIK, yes.. cvs unable to treat and understand unicode file properly during checkout. pass -kb when add file, should work

```
 cvs add -kb <unicode-file>
```

so that CVS thinks they're binary and leaves them alone (doesn't try to do *anything* with the contents of the file.) but there will be troublesome for diff and merge